# React gallery using react

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

```
import { AdvancedImage } from "@cloudinary/react";
import { fill } from "@cloudinary/url-gen/actions/resize";
import { byRadius } from "@cloudinary/url-gen/actions/roundCorners";


    const cld = new Cloudinary({
        cloud: {
        cloudName: "ifeomaimoh"
      }
});
    export const Turkish = () => {
      const file =
        "https://res.cloudinary.com/silorain/image/upload/v1653903645/Final%20Project/turkish/Screenshot_2022-05-30_at_10.39.47_j6pwll.png";
      let image = cld.image(file);
      image = image.setDeliveryType("fetch");
      image = image
        .resize(fill().height(500).width(490))
        .roundCorners(byRadius().radius(40))

    
      // This gives the full delivery URL of the tranformations applied above.
      console.log({ url: image.toURL() });
    
      return (
        <div style={{ padding: "5rem" }}>
          <AdvancedImage cldImg={image} />
        </div>
      );
    };
```

// I've got multiple folders in cloudinary and I am trying to get all the images in the folder to render on my local host. How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

so there are two ways to go about this. One is to use the Node SDK and serve your front end whatever methods you chose to implement using various APIs, guide to use those here https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521082-How-to-list-all-images-within-a-folder-.

If you want to just keep it all frontend, the other route is to just hit various endpoints through fetches. If you just need a list, Cloudinary also has a list URL; https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/list/logo.json. Then loop through your assets and add them as you did in the above code.